# How many recipients can i add in email template alert?

Tags: workflow, limits, email-alert

Could you please clarify my below queries on email alert which we have under workflow

1. How many recipients can i add under email alert?
2. Can i add group emailID (Eg. Supportmembersgroup@yahoo.com) which contains more than 50 recipients.

In Cc also I need to add more than 10 recipients, is email alert will work for this functionality Or I should go with apex class?

Comment: Workflow email alerts don't support cc:, only `Additional To` - limited to 5 constant email addresses, separated by commas.

Comment: Hi Chris! Thanks for sharing your thoughts, In additional recipients among that 5, can I add single group email (Eg. SupportMemberGroup@company.com)which contains more than 50 recipients? will it work?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below

Answer (score 6):

There are limits, but the limit you are likely going to hit is the daily limit for workflow emails.

[image]

You can though add an alias in the additional emails section.  Even if that alias (EntireCompany@yourcompany.com) redistributes that to hundreds of additional emails, its still just counts as a single workflow email towards your limit.

See the limits doc for yourself [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_workflow.htm)