# What is the limit for recipient list in email alerts

Tags: email-alert

We tried to get the information on How many recipients we can add in the recipients in Email alerts.

FYI, This is WRT Recipient field on email alerts i.e. users/opptyteam/owner/creater etc.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114896/how-many-recipients-can-i-add-in-email-template-alert

Answer (score 0):

You can specify up to 100 recipients for the To field.

Comment: Email alerts have no limit of themselves, and can send more than 100 emails at once. There are daily limits, but not per-alert limits.

Comment: @dhananjay if possible, Can you share reference doc from salesforce